# Pattern Matching or comparing two graphs (line charts)

Tags: python, graph, compare, pattern-matching

**Given:**

Ideal graph - Depicts the expected reading my machine should have. 
Actual graph - Depicts the actual reading my machine had at that instance.

X-axis: Force(N) from the machine

Y-axis: Time(s)

Both graphs were created using pyplot library in python.

**What I need to do:**

I need to compare the graph in its three phases: initialization (machine starts applying force), constant phase (constant force), end phase (machine stops applying force) and give the analysis of how close the phases in the actual read were to the ideal case (in terms of percentage). The analysis would allow me to conclude how the machine performed in those three phases for the actual read taken. I would need to do this for each reading taken every 50s.

**Hurdle:**

Now both the graphs were not created using the same number of data points. Ideal graph was created with 100 set of points and Actual graph was created using 30,000+ points. So I would not be able to compare the graphs using data points.

**Idea:**

Would it be wise to save the graph of the actual read as a png and compare it with the image of the ideal case graph?
Please give me some idea or solution to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

*It's a bit late but I'm going to answer anyway:*

I don't think resorting to a comparison of images is wise in this case, no.

What you probably want is to `interpolate` additional points between the 100 points on the 'Ideal graph' to match the 30,000+ points in the 'Actual graph'.

The [example on **1-D Interpolation**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#id3) in the `scipy.interpolate` docs seems to be exactly what you need.

If you need further assistance (such as working code), you will have to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to work with.